# Control Webform's date field (datepicker) from JS

Tags: 8, javascript, webforms, datetime

I have to change number of months that's shown in datepicker of my date field in Webform, on desktop I need 2 months, but on mobile just 1.

I'm not able to control that using JS, so I created patch for Webform module to change that and show 2 months.

Is there some solution for this, how I can change stuff like this using JS even I initialized it through field settings in Webform module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default datePicker's options by defining `Drupal.webform.datePicker.options` via the CSS/JS tab.

@see https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/js/webform.element.date.js

[image: Date picket options]

Answer (score 1):

You can override it with js .. the trick is when it is when your js is attached.

```
so in your module you need ....
<?php
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id === 'webform_submission_YOURFORMID') {
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'YOURMODULE/mymodule.fix-datepicker';
  }
}
```

then in your js please try some thing like..

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.fixMyDatepicker = {
attach: function (context) {

  var dateElement = $('#edit-1'); // id of your date picker 
  var dateData = dateElement.data();
  if (dateData.datepicker) {
    makeChangesToDatePicker();
  }
  else {
    var myInterv = setInterval(function() {
      if (dateData.datepicker) {
        makeChangesToDatePicker();
        clearInterval(myInterv);
      }
    }, 100);
  }

    function makeChangesToDatePicker() {
      //@TODO here check if mobile .
      var settings = dateData.datepicker.settings;
      settings.maxDate = '2019-03-11';
    }
   }
  };
 })(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

the above worked for me. remember datepicker is just: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/